# How to keep RSK project updated

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-starter-kit

I am developing `node` and `react` web app based on [react-starter-kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit).
As any project do, I override unnecessary code and files, and modify others as well.

Trying to keep up with the almost daily updates, I can't find a way to keep my project updated unless I resolve loads of conflicts every time.

The repository suggests to just merge to master, but it produces a lot of conflicts. Is there a quick and more reasonable way to do it?